# how to select different rows from mysql and update them in a single page

Tags: php, mysqli, multiple-columns

I want to select some rows from sql database . first user should insert two variable that I can select this rows . then in this page there is table that will update this rows but the problem is when I choose this columns without inputs I'm able to update the database but when I want to use input variables it shows the table but it cannot update it . where did I make a mistake ?

selecting databse columns without using inputs :

```
<?php
include 'mytool.php';
        // username and password sent from form
    $myusername=$_SESSION["mys"];

    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username='username'; // Mysql username
    $password='password'; // Mysql password
    $db_name="db"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="test"; // Table name

    // Connect to server and select database.

     $link=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)or die("cannot connect");
    $selected=mysql_select_db($db_name,$link)or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where classnum='106' and level='i4' ";

    $result=mysql_query($sql,$link);

    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);     

?>
```

input variables :

```
<form id="searchform" method="post" dir="rtl" action=""> 
                    level :<input name="level"  type="text" id="level" />
                    classnumber :<input name="classnum"  type="text" id="classnum" />

                           <input style="margin-top:10px; margin-left:120px; font-size: 14px;  padding: 5px 14px;" type="submit" value="search" name="enter"   />

                </form>

                <?php   
                    if(isset($_POST['enter'])){         
                    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where classnum='106' and level='i4' ";

                    $result=mysql_query($sql,$link);

                    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
                    }
                ?>
```

update table code after code above :

```
 <form name="form1" action="" method="POST">
                                <center>
                                    <div>
                                        <div align="center" width = 615>
                                            <table class="stats" cellspacing="0" width="615" border="1">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th width="20" scope="col" >Id</th>
                                                    <th width="60" scope="col">Name</th>
                                                    <th width="60" scope="col">Last Name</th>
                                                    <th width="42" scope="col">Midterm</th> 
                                                    <th width="54" scope="col">Class mark</th>
                                                    <th width="42" scope="col">Final Quiz</th>
                                                    <th width="54" scope="col">State</th>
                                                    <th width="54" scope="col">Details</th>

                                                </tr>
                                                <?php
                                                while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                                                    $id[]=$rows['id']; 
                                                 ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center">
                                                    <input name="id[]" type="text" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" >
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="name[]" id="name" value= "<? echo $rows['name']; ?>"  /></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="lastname[]" id="lastname" value= "<? echo $rows['lastname']; ?>"  /></td> 
                                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="midmark[]" id="midmark" /></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="classmark[]" id="classmark" /></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="finalmark[]" id="finalmark" /></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="state[]" id="state" /></td>
                                                    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="details[]" id="details"  /></td>

                                                </tr>
                                                <?php
                                                 }
                                                 ?>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>

                                <input type="submit" value="ثبت" name="Submit"   />
                                </form>

                                <?php
                                // Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
                                if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
                                {
                                     for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
                                     {
                                    $sql1=mysql_query(" UPDATE `".$tbl_name."` SET midmark='".$_REQUEST['midmark'][$i]."' , classmark='".$_REQUEST['classmark'][$i]."' , finalmark='".$_REQUEST['finalmark'][$i]."' , state='".$_REQUEST['state'][$i]."' , details='".$_REQUEST['details'][$i]."'  WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['id'][$i]."' ");
                                    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
                                    }
                                }

                                    if($result1){
                                    header("location:results.php");
                                    }
                                    mysql_close();
                                ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compare these lines.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
           {
                for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
                 {
                    **$sql1=mysql_query(" UPDATE `".$tbl_name."` SET midmark='".$_REQUEST['midmark'][$i]."' , classmark='".$_REQUEST['classmark'][$i]."' , finalmark='".$_REQUEST['finalmark'][$i]."' , state='".$_REQUEST['state'][$i]."' , details='".$_REQUEST['details'][$i]."'  WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['id'][$i]."' ");
                    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);**
                 }
           }
```

with these one.

```
$sql1=" UPDATE `".$tbl_name."` SET midmark='".$_REQUEST['midmark'][$i]."' , classmark='".$_REQUEST['classmark'][$i]."' , finalmark='".$_REQUEST['finalmark'][$i]."' , state='".$_REQUEST['state'][$i]."' , details='".$_REQUEST['details'][$i]."'  WHERE id='".$_REQUEST['id'][$i]."' ";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
```

Comment: can you tell me more specific ? with which line ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I confused what do you mean by comparing these lines ? the deference is between mysql_query in the first one . I've deleted this part but I still have the problem .

Comment: try adding error_reporting(E_ALL) for errors. paste any error if occured.

Comment: this errors happend :..........Notice: Undefined variable: result in /var/www/qeshmnewtechers/results.php on line 206 ................Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /var/www/qeshmnewtechers/results.php on line 206...................Notice: Undefined variable: count in /var/www/qeshmnewtechers/results.php on line 236...................Notice: Undefined variable: result1 in /var/www/qeshmnewtechers/results.php on line 243

Comment: can you paste line no. 206

Comment: line 206 :  <?php
            while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
             $id[]=$rows['id']; 
             ?>

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where classnum='106' and level='i4' ";   - this query having issue. check it in phpmyadmin or check the table columns.

Comment: thanks in advance for your consideration . this is the code page all of the codes are in it : https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbedsizmcbvfsgn/results.php?m

Comment: code does not having issue. is that "test" table exist in db with classnum and level columns in it?

Comment: yes it is. this is the databse screenshot : https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfpsaygo1m2olyx/database.png?m

Comment: remove the $link from line  $result=mysql_query($sql,$link); just use $result=mysql_query($link);

Comment: in line 159 in the code page that i uploadet in dropbox i changed it but still it is not working

Comment: remove $link from all occurrences.

Comment: one more point replace this query -    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where classnum='106' and level='i4' ";  with  $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where classnum='106' and \`level\`='i4' ";

Comment: I've done everything you said but notthing have changed . see the updated code : https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbedsizmcbvfsgn/results.php?m

Comment: when I change the place of lines : 157 159 161 to the 116 it works but I am not able to use inputs the code page : https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbedsizmcbvfsgn/results.php?m                                    .............edited code page :                     https://www.dropbox.com/s/gllu4zp02p7pfqt/resultsedited.php?m

Comment: look the problem is in this code if(isset($_POST['enter'])){ ....     when I write this code for an unknown reason it doesn't work I dont't know why ! but when i erase this like from the code it works !!!

Comment: First thing there is no code such as if(isset($_POST['enter'])){... in the file. it is if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){... which will definitely work as the submit button name is "Submit".  try print_r($_POST) to check it.

Comment: so here is a issue with submit . there are two submit button in this page one for search inputs one for updating table rows . I updated code to this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbedsizmcbvfsgn/results.php?m           .........              now when I load the oage it pass the first submit button without waiting for the user to press it and it'll wait for the second submit !!!

Comment: change the search form button name to "Search" or something then.

Comment: i changed the name to search . type is Submit . and if(isset($_POST['search'])){  . but it pass it like it's always set . but when I change if command to : if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) it's like it's always disable !!!

Comment: it doesn't work it just select all of the rows and it ignore submit button but when i change submit to search it works I mean it just creat the table but when i update it nothing is going to happen

Comment: please clear your requirement.  1. show no result by default.  2.search 3. show result 4. update records   is this your requirement?

Comment: yes 1- no data or information . 2- search for two inputs . 3- show the rows or columns from database. 4- update them and again come back to this page .

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not updating the rows it just shows the selected rows and I've tried it before.

Comment: i have updated code. use this code and let me know if any error occured. https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqawbvuieod8igu/results.php?m

Comment: I don't know how to thank you . It worked Thanks again.   just one more thing is there anyway to reset the input values after reloading the page ? because after updating the page search inputs are still in fields.

Comment: at last. :). i made that change because message is saying that values are updated and user need to see updated changes so kept flow like that. you can change it the way you want.